# IIS Asp.net 4.6 website goes to sleep after 1-2 mins

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dll, iis-8

I have a pretty plain asp.net website with a few addons. It seems the website goes to "sleep mode" every 1-2 mins and you have to wake it up again, which takes about 10-15 secs before the server responds again.

If you refresh the page after 15-30 secs it renders the page instantly.

Here's what I've tried to so far without any luck:
Changed the advanced settings for "Idle Time-out" to 0 in Application Pool.
Changed the advanced settings for "Idle Time-out Action" to Suspend instead of Terminate in Application Pool.

List of dll files I use - /Bin

```
DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.dll
DotNetOpenAuth.Core.dll
DotNetOpenAuth.Core.UI.dll
DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.dll
DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.dll
MySql.Data.dll
Newtonsoft.Json.dll
Org.Mentalis.Security.Cryptography.dll
```

It's running on Windows 2012 R2.

Let me know if you need to know if there's anything I missed.

Comment: Have you disabled periodic app pool recycling? See https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/recycling

Comment: I will check that right now. Thanks.

Comment: I set the "Disable Overlapped Recycle" to True and "Disable Recycle for Configuration Changes" to True and it seems it works now. Thanks!!!